# GLM quaternion reversed yaw

Tags: opengl, game-engine, quaternions, glm-math

I am building a toy 3D engine using OpenGL and GLM. My axis system is right-handed, with X to the right, Y up and Z back.

An entity's transform is made up of a 3D vector and one of GLM's quaternions. The physics simluation is in 2D, so an entity's velocity is a 2D vector (there is no velocity on Y, only on XZ, the ground plane). Similarly, the angular velocity is only around the Y axis (yaw).

```
// Properly integrate the change in velocities
auto deltaPos = (physics->velocity + physics->lastVelocity) * 0.5f * deltaTime;
auto deltaYaw = (physics->yawVelocity + physics->lastYawVelocity) * 0.5f * deltaTime;
// Apply the velocities
transform->position += glm::vec3 {deltaPos.x, 0, deltaPos.y} * transform->orientation
transform->orientation = glm::quat(glm::vec3 {0, deltaYaw, 0}) * transform->orientation;
```

I'm rendering the world with a top-down camera, converting the orientation to a 4x4 matrix, multiplying it (in the right order) with a scale and translation matrix:

```
glm::mat4x4 transformMat =
        glm::translate(transform->position) *
        glm::mat4x4(transform->orientation) *
        glm::scale(glm::vec3 {size.x, 1.0f, size.y});
```

.. and sending it to the shader, where it's multiplied with the point coordinates and the projection and view matrices:

```
// projView is projection * view
gl_Position = projView * transform * vec4(vertPosition.xyz, 1.0);
```

However, while this code seems straightforward, the yaw of the objects seems to be sometimes flipped. When an object turns left, it starts moving left in the world (the `position += deltaPosition * orientation` line works properly), but it is rendered as rotating to the right, but moving to the left. This is an example image:

[image: yaw problem example]

It seems like quaternion's representation, or at least its quaternion - matrix conversion, negates the yaw "component", of the rotation, acting like Y is down, instead of up. However, when a vector is rotated by that quaternion, it seems to act properly, like Y is up. Interestingly, another part of the code (dealing with the vehicle's turns) seems to work properly only when the quaternion is rotated by -yaw instead of yaw. (The rendering issue persists).

Any explanations or means to fix this problem?

Comment: Why are you trying to rotate the velocity by the orientation? Is it stored in the object's local coordinate system? Furthermore, is the code `vector * quaternion` a valid quaternion transformation in glm? Usually, you do `quaternion * vector * quaternion^-1`, where `vector` is the quaternionized vector.

Comment: Thank you, the `vector * quaternion` line was actually performing a rotation (it seems to be some sort of GLM notation), but it was rotating by quaternion^-1, which was causing all the trouble with rotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was applying the quaternions wrongly:
On this line:

```
transform->position += glm::vec3 {deltaPos.x, 0, deltaPos.y} * transform->orientation
```

the multiplication's definition in GLM was actually rotating the vector by the inverse of the quaternion. The correct line was:

```
transform->position += transform->orientation * glm::vec3 {deltaPos.x, 0, deltaPos.y};
```

Thank you to Nico Schertler for directing my attention in the right direction.